# sort-bed command not found

Tags: linux, scripting, bioinformatics, command-not-found

I have the following code " not mine"

```
wget -qO- http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/database/snp142Common.txt.gz \
    | gunzip -c - \
    | cut -f2,3,4,5,10 - \
    | sort-bed - \
    > hg19.snp142.bed
```

when I run it on terminal it gave me the following error

sort-bed: command not found

how to fix it?

Comment: Where did you get the command from?   I've never heard of the `sort-bed` command but I don't have it either.  http://bedops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/reference/file-management/sorting/sort-bed.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sort-bed`](http://bedops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/reference/file-management/sorting/sort-bed.html) is contained in **BEDOPS: the fast, highly scalable and easily-parallelizable genome analysis toolkit**, which can be easily installed following [these steps](http://bedops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/installation.html#linux):

1. Download the current 64-bit package for Linux from [Github BEDOPS Releases](https://github.com/bedops/bedops/releases). 32-bit binaries can be built via source code by adjusting compile-time variables, see [here](http://bedops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/installation.html#installation-via-source-code-on-linux).
2. Extract the package to a location of your choice. In the case of 64-bit Linux:

   ```
   tar jxvf bedops_linux_x86_64-vx.y.z.tar.bz2
   ```

   Replace `x`, `y` and `z` with the version number of BEDOPS you have downloaded.
3. Copy the extracted binaries to a location of your choice which is in your environment’s `PATH`, e.g. `/usr/local/bin`:

   ```
   cp bin/* /usr/local/bin
   ```

   Change this destination folder, as needed.